# Picture quality of video capture file produced using Virtualdub is excellent when played on my laptop but not on my smart TV. How can I fix this?

Tags: video-quality, video-capture

I'm trying to digitise some old Hi8 camcorder tapes using VirtualDub 1.10.4 with lagarith lossless codec compression and a Magix USB video converter 5 capture card.

When the captured file is played on my Windows 10 laptop using the latest version of Pot Player with deinterlace setting BOB (2x frame) the picture quality is sharp and motion beautifully smooth.

When I play the file on my LG Smart TV (after conversion to a readable format using Handbrake) the picture is awful (much like the video capture monitoring screen on VirtualDub): motion is blurred and the picture is full of lines or combs.  Playback is fine on Pot Player.

Please can you suggest how I can capture a file that looks as good on my TV as on my laptop.

I've tried numerous combinations of codecs for compression and playback, but no use.

The picture quality on my laptop seems better than using Magix Rescue Your Videotapes, which is why I'm trying VirtualDub.

Comment: You'll need to look at what formats your TV natively supports. It sounds like Handbrake is outputting something that your TV cannot use.

Comment: @DrMayhem. I don't know where I can get info on supported formats for my TV, but as I've indicated I've tried numerous formats, but while most will play, all the one's that will play give the same result or worse. I also want to preserve the smooth video of the original. Please find a link to one of my raw video capture files which you can play around with. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jJEYBieAGQisK43xvDVU4FmxbWO1_F1C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Of the steps you list, the only one that makes a difference is what you are doing with Handbrake. The capture is obviously fine, but whatever you are converting it to at that point is the problem.